# How do I find out specificity/sensitivity/predictive value with only prevalence and # of positives

Tags: sensitivity-specificity

I understand that

```
specificity = True Positive / (True Positive + False negative)
sensitivity = True negative / (False positive + True negative)

positive pv = True positive / (True positive + False positive)
negative pv = True negative / (true negative + False negative)
```

However, assume I know only which percent of population is resulted as positive in a certain test. also, I do know the prevalence. How can I calculate specificity/sensitivity/predictive values in this case?

the question can be reduced into:

```
fill blanks given x, y, z, w
          test    diagnosis    sum
positive    ?         ?         x
negative    ?         ?         y
sum         z         w
```

Comment: 'test' and 'diagnosis' aren't the best labels here, I think. Maybe "Ill" and "Well" or some such?

Comment: I don't think you can - that is really the point of specificity/sensitivity etc. to tell you how good a test it.  The margins, by definition really,  don't tell you the joint relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

You have 4 equations for 4 variables, but only 3 of these equations are independent (i.e., the rank of the 4x4 matrix is only 3).

This is because (in your notations) `x+y=z+w`.